# Getting Resources from another package

Tags: android, resources, package

Inside src/ I have the following packages:com.app.animals, com.app.animals.threads, com.app.animals.games

When I try to get my proyect resources (drawable folder) from a class called "CarreraJuego.java" inside com.app.animals.games, it says that 'R cannot be resolved to a variable'

How can I access resources folder from that package?The class is a surfaceview

Comment: Are you sure you have imported the R class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a simple and quick way to achieve it:

```
try
{
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    Resources resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication("com.example.packagename");
    int resId = resources.getIdentifier("drawable_id", "drawable", "com.example.packagename");

    Drawable myDrawable = resources.getDrawable(resId);

    // Do something
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Change `com.example.packagename` width the package name of the app you need the resources.
Change `drawable_id` with the resource Id.
Change `drawable` to the folder name you want (`drawable`, `layout`, `values`, ...)

Comment: Is it also possible to iterate over all resources of a given app?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is import the R.java file inside the classes of packages outside of the main package (the one with the generated R file)